# Seeking shareable online Oracle instance (with Oracle Spatial enabled)

Tags: oracle-spatial, service-recommendations

Are there any shareable/public online Oracle instances that have Oracle Spatial enabled?

Use Case:

Mock up a Oracle Spatial SQL problem/solution and easily share it via a public URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like db<>fiddle (dbfiddle.uk) can be used for this.

- https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=4d0fa4122fd519d734c4c16695fb76c7

> [image]

---

Notes:

1. The Oracle 18c and 21c versions of db<>fiddle seem to have Oracle Spatial enabled. But 11gR2 [threw a few errors](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4d0fa4122fd519d734c4c16695fb76c7), so my best guess is that Spatial isn't enabled in 11gR2.
2. In 18c and 21, I tested using this example: [Snap a point to a line and get the line ID](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/352692/snap-a-point-to-a-line-and-get-the-line-id-oracle-spatial-or-sde-st-geometry). Db<>fiddle was able to successfully use the Linear Referencing package, which I believe is only available in Oracle Spatial—proving that Spatial is enabled.

   - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=4d0fa4122fd519d734c4c16695fb76c7
3. The only trouble I had was that db<>fiddle didn’t know how to select rows where there was a column with the SDO_GEOMETRY datatype. Often, SQL clients are able to select some basic text from that datatype. But db<>fiddle seemed to just not select any rows at all, which was confusing. I had to explicitly convert the column to text in order to select rows. But once I did that, it worked.
4. https://dbfiddle.uk is not to be confused with http://www.db-fiddle.com or https://sqlfiddle.com. The first link is used heavily by the guys on https://dba.stackexchange.com. I don't have any experience with the second or third links. Although it seems like DBAs prefer to use the first one.
5. The sessions in https://dbfiddle.uk are permanent, public, and shareable. Just copy the URL to share the work that you did.
6. Each line is an individual SQL statement. As far as I can tell, we can't put multiple statements in a single line. But, I think there are tricks for bulk-inserting data like putting a bunch of test data in a single WITH clause (Toad can generate the WITH clause automatically). There are probably other tricks too.
7. Sometimes, a SQL statement needs to end with a `/` . Similar to SQL Plus. More info here: [DB<>Fiddle: Custom type and function (ORA-24344)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/300186/171339)

---

[Oracle Live SQL](https://livesql.oracle.com/) is similar, but different.

- I assume Oracle Spatial is also enabled in Oracle Live SQL: https://livesql.oracle.com/
- But I'm guessing those sessions aren't permanent/shareable. So https://dbfiddle.uk might be a better option.